# React App "Unbound breakpoint" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Can't debug React App in Visual Studio Code. I have "Debugger for Firefox","Debugger for Chrome" and the default "JavaScript Debugger" extensions. I done it before, not sure what happen in meantime.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. npm run build
2. npm start (serve -s build for prod)
3. set launch.json (auto-generated by VS Code, just change the port)
4. Start in debug mode
5. Hit breakpoint
6. :)

```
launch.json 
{
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/"
},
```